# Inferring a generic type from a generic type in Java (compile time error)

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a static function with the following signature for a generic type `T`

```
public static<T> List<T> sortMap(Map<T, Comparable> map)
```

which should return a list of map keys with some property.

Now I want to pass a generic HashMap of type `S`

```
Map<S,Double> map
```

in calling the static function within a generic class, which has the map as a member variable.

I have listed a minimal code example below.

However, I get an error message (`S` and `T` are both T's but in different scopes of my code, i.e. `T#1` = `T`, `T#2`= `S`):

```
  required: Map<T#1,Comparable>
  found: Map<T#2,Double>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
  (argument mismatch; Map<T#2,Double> cannot be converted to Map<T#1,Comparable>)
```

How can resolve this issue? I am surprised that Java does not allow inferring a generic type from a generic type. What structure in Java can one use to work with that kind of more abstract code reasoning?

**Code**:

```
public class ExampleClass<T> {
    Map<T, Double> map;
    public ExampleClass () {
        this.map = new HashMap();
    }
    //the following line produces the mentioned error
    List<T> sortedMapKeys = UtilityMethods.sortMap(map);
}

public class UtilityMethods {
     public static<T> List<T> sortMap(Map<T, Comparable> map) {
        // sort the map in some way and return the list
     }
}
```

Comment: Please show the class code the audience.

Comment: ``static`` methods cannot access member variables; and what version of java do you use?

Comment: I think you'll have to add some more code for us to understand the problem.

Comment: BTW you cannot use `Map<S,Double>` to pass to a method that needs `Map<T, Comparable>`. `Double` and `Comparable` are different types with different inheritance hierarchies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the problem with the `T` and `S`, but with the `Comparable` and `Double`.

The reason for the error is that a [`Map<T, Double>` is not a `Map<T, Comparable>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/1003142).

You'll have to widen a bit the scope of the second type-parameter. Something like:

```
public static <T, S extends Comparable<S>> List<T> function(Map<T, S> map) {
    //implementation
}
```

Then, you'll be able to invoke the method with:

```
Map<S, Double> map = new HashMap<S, Double>();
function(map);
```

Comment: this is called [variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I was misled by the compiler message focussing on the generic types. Also, I thought the compiler would understand that `Double` is `Comparable` and that interfaces would be handled differently than class inheritance for generics. I still think that the Java logic of using the `extends` keyword in generics for describing that I expect a type `S`that *implements* and interface is a little off. Do I miss something here? Does it make sense to *extend and interface* with generics?

Comment: Yes, `extends` in Generics is used for both classes and interfaces.

Comment: for best results use `S extends Comparable<? super S>`